# Using "multiple" MultiDataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to show/hide buttons on ListBox items by using multiple data triggers. The problem it doesn't work properly.

The changes of the properties are triggering well however the conditions seems not to be met.

This is how I use the triggers. Simply an if/else block.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>

                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDownloading}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding downloaded}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonDownload" Property="Visibility" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DownloadProgressPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDownloading}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding downloaded}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="DownloadProgressPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonDownload" Property="Visibility" Value="1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <MultiDataTrigger>

                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDownloading}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding downloaded}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="DownloadProgressPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonDownload" Property="Visibility" Value="0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding favouriteListType}" Value="8">
                        <Setter TargetName="URLButtonsPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>


            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you include the rest of the complete DataTemplate (as in a [mcve])? Maybe you are overriding certain properties elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't your setter values for `Visibility` be in the range `Visible,Hidden,Collapsed` instead of bringing `0` and `1` to the party?

Comment: *Property="Visibility" Value="1"* sure, why not put random values in the Visibility property and see if it works. Sounds like a plan.  Try "foo" next.